# How to trigger fancy box from an input (focusout)

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I'm trying to trigger Fancybox when the user focuses out of an input box and the value within is over a fixed amount (25). The focus out and checking value code seem fine, but Fancy box throws the following error when triggered:

`Node cannot be inserted at the specified point in the hierarchy`

My HTML is:

`<input class='warning' type='text' name='cash' />`

and th JS (in document ready) is:

```
$(".warning").focusout(function() {
  if (Number(this.value) > 25)  {
    console.debug(this.value + " gt 25");
    $.fancybox({
      showCloseButton: false,
      href: 'warning.html'
    });
  }
})
```

I suspect the problem is in the $.fancybox bit, but I can't tell what it should be!

Comment: Which version of fancybox are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the closing brace on the if() clause.

http://jsfiddle.net/PxySJ/1/ works fine with it.

Comment: Hi, sorry I'd missed that out when I cut and pasted it into stack overflow, the closing  brace was in my code all along. The code runs as far as the fancybox call when it displays to error shown in my post. Thanks for your reply though

Comment: The jsfiddle I posted replicates everything you've told us about the problem and it works fine. You will have to give more information or post more of the markup or something, but we can't help based on what you've posted here because there is nothing wrong with it (after fixing the braces).

Comment: Strange seems to be working now on IE which is what I need, FF keeps throwing that node error though, even on a standard `<a href='xxx' class='fancybox'>` link with none of that extra code above

Comment: Very odd, it works ok for me on FF14. It would mean a bit of extra work but I would advise upgrading to the latest version of fancybox (2+ now http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) it may have fixed whatever weird bug would cause this.